# MySQL datediff function not available in SQLite used for unit tests

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sqlite, phpunit

I have used the following Raw query in my Laravel project.

```php
$statisticsInRangeDate = $myModel->selectRaw(
    "floor(datediff(created_at, '{$dateInfo['currentRangeDate']}')".
    " / {$dateInfo['daysRange']}) * {$dateInfo['daysRange']} AS diff_days_range, count(*) as total_clicks, ".
    'min(created_at) ,max(created_at)'
)
    ->groupByRaw('diff_days_range')
    ->orderByRaw('diff_days_range DESC')
    ->get();
```

The raw query is:

```sql
select
    floor(datediff(created_at, '2023-04-04') / 3) * 3 AS diff_days_range,
    count(*) as total_install,
    min(created_at),
    max(created_at) 
from sdk_clicks 
where sdk_clicks.application_id = 1
    and sdk_clicks.application_id is not null
    and created_at >= '2023-04-01'
    and created_at < '2023-04-07'
    and sdk_clicks.deleted_at is null
group by diff_days_range
order by diff_days_range
```

The database of the project is mysql and I get the necessary output, but I get the following error when running the phpunit tests which use a sqlite memory database for speed.

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such function: datediff (SQL: select floor...

I have the knowledge that this function does not exist in sqlite and `julianday('now') - julianday(DateCreated)` should be used for the time difference, but I am looking for the best solution to solve this problem automatically by detecting the type of database and the appropriate function be used.

---

Note: Due to the need for high speed test, I want to use memory and sqlite database

Comment: I will say that the answer is pretty obvious... you can't use SQLite or just do not use RAW sql and use the DB facade or a model and let that DRIVE the query as intented... Try to avoid raw sql as much as possible...

Comment: You may also consider using MySQL, but in your test environment, define tables using the [MEMORY storage engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html).

Comment: If you need to test code that relies heavily on non-basic sql stuff, you will be better off making a separate mysql database just for testing purposes. It will be slower than a sqlite database but you will be sure and certain that the queries behave the same way. Using the memory storage engine could mitigate it but in my experience, it does not always work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the possibility of using [Macro in laravel](https://www.larashout.com/laravel-macros-extending-laravels-core-classes), it allows me to add new functions to `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

On my AppServiceProvider.php I create the macro rangeDateDiff() :

```php
Builder::macro('rangeDateDiff',
            function ($firstDate, $secondDate, $daysRange = 1, string $as = 'diff_days_range') {
            if ($this->getConnection()->getDriverName() == 'sqlite') {
                $this->addSelect(\DB::raw(
                    "floor (cast (julianday(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', {$firstDate})) - julianday(strftime('%Y-%m-%d', {$secondDate})) As Integer)"
                    . " / {$daysRange}) * {$daysRange} AS {$as}")
                );
            } else {
                $this->addSelect(\DB::raw(
                    "floor(datediff({$firstDate}, {$secondDate})"
                    . " / {$daysRange}) * {$daysRange} AS {$as}")
                );
            }

            return $this;
        });
```

then use this new function globaly in Eloquent model :

```php
$sdkClicks = $this->application->sdkClicks()
            ->where('created_at', '>=', $dateInfo['previousRangeDate'])
            ->where('created_at', '<', $dateInfo['toDate']->format('Y-m-d'));

        $sdkClicks->rangeDateDiff('created_at', "'{$dateInfo['currentRangeDate']}'", $dateInfo['daysRange'])
            ->groupByRaw('diff_days_range')
            ->orderByRaw('diff_days_range DESC')->get();
```

The advantage of this method is that it's **more clean**, and most importantly, if another type of database needs to be used in the project, the code is more **maintainable**.

Comment: You could accept your answer so future visitors will instantly see that the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thanks @LajosArpad for comment and vote ,I was waiting for other people to vote on my answer and confirm the answer with more certainty.

Answer (score 2):

PHP provides the ability to create user defined functions in sqlite. This is done using the [`PDO::sqliteCreateFunction()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.sqlitecreatefunction.php).

Basically, you're defining a function inside of sqlite that will call the PHP code you provide.

Your code would look something like:

```
$pdo = DB::connection()->getPdo();

// Only do this if using sqlite.
if ($pdo->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DRIVER_NAME) != 'sqlite') {
    return;
}

$pdo->sqliteCreateFunction(
    'datediff', // name of the sqlite function to create
    function ($first, $second) {
        $dateFirst = Carbon\Carbon::parse($first)->startOfDay();
        $dateSecond = Carbon\Carbon::parse($second)->startOfDay();
        
        return $dateSecond->diffInDays($dateFirst, false);
    }, // PHP callback function implementation
    2 // number of parameters the sqlite function takes
);
```

Add this somewhere in your test suite before the query is executed, and you should be good.

Comment: This is true, but the idea of the author is to be fast, creating it's own method and using PHP in the middle defeats the purpouse of "performance"/"fast" tests (DB vs PHP), so this is a solution if the user does not want to use MySQL and still wants to continue with SQLite. In that case, I think this is crazy, adding this stuff so "tests are fast with SQLite", you are sort of engineering a method for the DB, that is a massive no for anyone, but still, this is a valid answer for any crazy person that want's to still follow this path (not using production's setup but for local tests)

Comment: @matiaslauriti, an in-memory sqlite database with a UDF is still faster than a mysql database, so no, it doesn't defeat the OP's purpose of a fast test suite. Additionally, any performance hit would only be incurred on those tests that run the query with the UDF. The rest of the test suite would be unaffected; unlike converting the entire test suite to use a slower mysql database.